How to output milliseconds using FireDAC FDBatchMove with TSQLTimeStamp fields?
I'm using TFDBatchMove to transfer data from a table to a CSV file.
object FDBatchMoveDataSetReader1: TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader
  DataSet = TblTrip
  Left = 224
  Top = 144
end
object FDBatchMove1: TFDBatchMove
  Reader = FDBatchMoveDataSetReader1
  Writer = FDBatchMoveTextWriter1
  Mappings = <>
  LogFileName = 'Data.log'
  CommitCount = 999
  OnProgress = FDBatchMove1Progress
  OnWriteValue = FDBatchMove1WriteValue
  Left = 280
  Top = 96
end
object FDBatchMoveTextWriter1: TFDBatchMoveTextWriter
  FileName = 'C:\Temp\Dump.txt'
  DataDef.Fields = <>
  DataDef.FormatSettings.ShortTimeFormat = 'HH:mm.zzz'
  Left = 320
  Top = 144
end

The table has a couple of TimeStamp fields:
object TblTrip: TFDTable
  IndexFieldNames = 'TripPkey'
  Connection = ADSConnection
  UpdateOptions.UpdateTableName = 'TRIP'
  TableName = 'TRIP'
  Left = 40
  Top = 240
  ...
  object TblTripOpenedDateTime: TSQLTimeStampField
    FieldName = 'OpenedDateTime'
    Origin = 'OpenedDateTime'
    DisplayFormat = 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.zzz'
  end

No matter what settings I toggle on the TFDBatchMoveTextWriter or the TSQLTimeStamp field, I cannot get the output to include milliseconds.
Here's a sample:
"208GVGqETJAY2:[4",2,"45745",1,2/13/2008 5:02:08 PM,,"","","",,F,F,0,F,F,F,F,F,,,"","","","",

I tried intercepting in the TFDBatchMove.OnWriteValue event:
AValue := StrToDateTime(FormatDateTime('mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.zzz', AValue));

But I am not gaining any ground.
I need the milliseconds to be included in the output.

Do you realize that AValue := StrToDateTime(FormatDateTime('mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.zzz', AValue)); is effectively just AValue := AValue;? It is useless to convert a TDateTime to a string and back to a TDateTime, that is not going to do anything to add any missing components to whoever uses the TDateTime afterwards.

Sure, that makes sense. I went through a few variations inside of OnWriteValue, but nothing works yet.

Are you sure that DataDef.FormatSettings.ShortTimeFormat even takes milliseconds into account? System.SysUtils.TFormatSettings.ShortTimeFormat outputs time using only hours and minutes. You may need to use [System.DateUtils.DecodeDateTimeg(https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Athens/en/System.DateUtils.DecodeDateTime) from DateUtils unit as it can work with milliseconds.

@SilverWarior your first link is to a wrong class (should be for TFDTextDataDef.FormatSettings - there's no help) and in my simple test changing DataDef.FormatSettings.ShortTimeFormat was enough to get miliseconds in the output file, so there's something else involved on OP's side.

@BrakNicku I know my first link doesn't show to correct class. But the reason why I chose that one is because TFDTextDataDef.FormatSettings documentation lacks any useful information and I assume they might work in similar manner. Also i don't have access to development computer at this moment to do a proper test.

@BrakNicku can I see your DFM for the TFDBatchMoveTextWriter? Specifically what you used for ShortDateFormat. What was your datasetreader hooked to? Did it have a TSQLTimestampField?

The dfm is the same as in Q (DataDef.FormatSettings.ShortTimeFormat = 'hh:mm:ss.zzz). Reader has TFDTable with TSQLTimeStampField assigned. Nothing else needed. I'm using 10.4.

Maybe it has something to do with the underlying database. I'm using Advantage but I can try with postgresql.  What database are you using?
